# MySQL Do a JOIN even if related rows dont exist?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, accounts and programs. Programs has a foreign key account_id that ties it to the account.

So I have:

```
Account:
id
Name

Program:
id
account_id
name
```

I want to be able to query something like

```
SELECT *, count(program.id) AS program_count From Account
```

but this doesnt work if there are no programs that link back to an Account row.

Any insight or tips on what to do or how to go about this?

Comment: If you down vote, please provide some info as to why

Comment: The site is generally not about swapping ideas for code. Read up on [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax, try it out then come back with a question when things don't work out.

Comment: Surely that's "Do a JOIN EVEN IF related rows DON'T exist?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Account.*, count(program.id) AS program_count 
FROM Account
LEFT JOIN program
ON Account.id = Program.account_id
GROUP BY Account.id
```

Comment: To make this a not-just-code answer, why not elaborate on what a `LEFT JOIN` is to *really* answer this question?